# Line Input # statement, three lines the same. Will it overwrite the variable each time?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

In a program I am migrating from vb6 to VB.net, there are three Line Input# statements, all the same:

```
Line Input #9, dummy
Line Input #9, dummy
Line Input #9, dummy
```

Will this just overwrite the variable each time, or do something stupid like append the input to dummy each time?

My second question, what's the difference between Input# and Line Input#? I had been using:

```
foo = bar.readline
```

for Input #.. and now I'm afraid that I've done it all wrong and should have used:

```
foo = bar.Read
```

or something
All help greatly appreciated
Thanks guys!
Nick

Comment: Since the variable is called "dummy", the purpose of these code lines is probably to ignore three lines of text from the input file. So overwriting "dummy" is OK here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Line Input` statement reads all the text in the input file up until the next `CR` or `CR-LF` sequence and puts it in the variable `dummy`. So these statements will, as you surmise, overwrite the variable `dummy` each time.

`Input` reads input until the next `CR`, `CR-LF` sequence or delimiting comma, and saves the data read in `dummy`.

I'm inclined to the view that you are right, you should really use `bar.Read` for `Input #` and `bar.ReadLine` for `Input Line`.

See [Input #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243386(v=VS.60).aspx) and [Line Input #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243392(v=vs.60).aspx) for more.

Comment: As the example in the documentation for `Input #` says, `"1,2""X"` is read as two strings, `"1,2"` and `"X"` - so it's not just commas as separators within the line. That's why I'd recommend using the already built VB6 interop classes.

Comment: Before recommending the use of the interop classes for VB6, it would be useful to know what the program actually does.  Rather than just a blind conversion, perhaps using a StreamReader or BinaryReader could be used.

Answer (score 4):

The language reference is still, surprisingly, available. [Input #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243386%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [Line Input #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243392%28v=VS.60%29.aspx). You're correct that they are *not* the same.

To your first question, it will overwrite the variable, so it just seems to be a way to skip 2 lines and read the third line.

---

You're probably better off using the VB Runtime facilities to read files that have been produced by VB 6, rather than the ".NET" style of filesystem work, since I think it would be quite difficult to reproduce the behaviour of `Input #` using `Read`. Use [`FileSystem.Input`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.input.aspx) instead.

Comment: I had read those, but to me they sound pretty much the same, except the Line Input # specifically states that it reads a single line, does that mean that Input # reads more than one?

Comment: +1 but if you are trying to reproduce `LineInput` I suggest you use [`FileSystem.LineInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.lineinput.aspx) !

Answer (score 2):

The [Line Input #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243392%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) command doesn't do anything special like appending to the variable. The value is simply assigned to the varaible, so if you have three lines like that it will overwrite the first two values.

The `Read #` command expects a special format for the data, so `ReadLine` won't work as a replacement. The reference for the [Write #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw69s8t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) command has details for how the data looks that the `Read #` command expects.